# What is a proper method for minimizing st deviation of dependent variable (e.g. clustering?)

Tags: sas, cluster-analysis, regression, stata, spss

I'm stuck with minimizing the st deviation of a dependent variable being time difference in days. The mean is OK, but the deviation is terrible. Tried clustering by independent variables and noticed quite dissimilar clusters. Now, wondering:
1) How I can actually apply this knowledge from clustering to the independent variable? The fact is that it was not included in initial clustering analysis, as I know it's dependent on the others.
2) Given that I know the variable of time difference is dependent, should I run clustering of it with the variable of cluster number being the result of my initial clustering analysis? Would it help?
3) Is there any other technique apart from clustering that can help me somehow categorize observation groups so that for each group I would have a separate mean of the independent variable with low st deviation?

Any help highly appreciated!

P.S. I was using Stata and SPSS, though I can also use SAS if you can share the code.

Comment: This is not a Stata programming question. Please show a reproducible example, your code, any errors, and the expected output. A general question about clustering is a better fit for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're going about this all wrong. Here are some relevant points to consider.

It's more important for the variance to be consistent across groups than it is to be low.

Clustering is (generally) going to organize individuals based on similar patterns of the clustering variables.

Fewer observations will generally not decrease the size of your standard deviation.

Any time you take continuous variables (either IV or DVs) and convert them into categorical variables, you are removing variance from the equation, and including more measurement error. Sometimes there are good reasons to do this, often times there are not.

Analysis should be theory-driven whenever possible, as data driven analysis (like what you're trying to accomplish here) is more likely to produce results that can't be reproduced or generalized to other data sets, samples, or populations.